# One big fat DTO vs multiple skinny DTO

Tags: c#, design-patterns, dto, data-transfer-objects

I'm always struggling with naming convention and design pattern for my application, it's been very hard to keep it consistent, so I have a simple case, let's say I have a service with method called `CreateOrder`

```
public OrderDTO CreateOrder(int customerID, OrderShipDTO shipping, OrderDetailDTO products);
```

Here's the DTO class

```
    public class OrderDTO
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public decimal PriceTotal { get; set; }
        public string Status { get; set; }
        public string PaymentMethod { get; set; }

        public OrderShipDTO OrderShip { get; set; }
        public ICollection<OrderDetailDTO> OrderDetails { get; set; }
    }
    public class OrderShipDTO
    {
        public string Name { get; set; }
        public string Phone { get; set; }
        public string Address { get; set; }
        public string Province { get; set; }
        public string City { get; set; }
        public string District { get; set; }
        public string SubDistrict { get; set; }
        public string ZipCode { get; set; }
    }

    public class OrderDetailDTO
    {
        public int ID { get; set; }
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
        public decimal Price { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
    }
```

As you can see, my method `CreateOrder` will return `OrderDTO` and accept `OrderDetailDTO` parameters, but the method actually only requires property `OrderDetailDTO.ProductID` and `OrderDetailDTO.Quantity` for the business logic calculation.

So, it feels not right for me (and confusing because I wasn't sure which properties need to have a value and which doesn't) to pass the entire `OrderDetailDTO` object even though it only needs 2 of the properties to be filled, but I still need to pass back the `OrderDTO` which will include `ICollection<OrderDetailDTO>` because I need to get the `OrderDetailDTO.Price` value and show it to my customer.

So I was thinking of creating another DTO like this

```
    public class OrderDetailDTO_2 //temp name
    {
        public decimal Quantity { get; set; }
        public int ProductID { get; set; }
    }
```

But I will end up with a lot of DTOs and even though I'm fine with it, what's the best practice for the DTO naming?

Comment: Are you happy to have  OrderDetailDTO_2 as an abstract class to OrderDetailDTO? & order details changes to `public ICollection<OrderDetailDTO_2> OrderDetails { get; set; }`?

Answer (score 1):

I don't see the point (from the posted info) in having an ID and a ProductId in an orderdetail because the ProductId should be sufficient; if the user adds 2 apples and then adds 3 apples, you can just set the order quantity to 5 apples for the single apples line, rather than distinctly track 2 apples vs 3 apples lines

I don't see the point in not having the price in the orderdetail; items always have a price. It might change or not, but there's no harm in communicating the price to the front end with every back and forth- the front end doesn't have to remember anything then, leading to my next point:

I also don't see the point in having the total in the order unless it is somehow ever going to be different to the sum of all the detail quantity * price. The client can do sums just like the server can. If the client knows the quantity and price, have it work out the total itself

I don't think OrderShip is well named. OrderShip is actually an Address, and looks like it could have plenty of uses in other parts of the program like a billing address, invoicing address, correspondence address. Name your objects according to what they *are* rather than what they *are for* - use the name of the variable to indicate what it is for:

```
public AddressDto ShippingAddress ...
public AddressDto BillingAddress ...
```

> I was thinking of creating another DTO like this

Do not ever create a class name and just whack a 2 on it "because you couldn't think of a better name" - it is absolutely zero help in letting another developer (or yourself by the time you've forgotten this project) know the difference. Hands up anyone who can tell me every difference between an oracle sql VARCHAR and VARCHAR2 without hitting the manual (Gordon, this one's for everyone else ;) )

> the method actually only requires property OrderDetailDTO.ProductID and OrderDetailDTO.Quantity for the business logic calculation.

You didn't post any code but there is a reasonable point in the comments that classes can inherit; the base class can have the common properties all classes have, the subclass can have more properties, plus it gets the base ones. The client could send a base class "I want to order apples, 3" and get a subclass "order item apples, 3, $1"

I'm not sure that these arguments warrant creating a whole new class just to dispense with 1 property though. I'd just reuse the same class and sometimes its price is filled in (server to client) and sometimes not/doesn't have to be/ignored (client to server, don't want client setting the prices!)

> so I have a simple case, let's say I have a service with method called CreateOrder

Creating an order isn't what I'd call a simple case; it wouldn't need an SO question if it were - your create order method doesn't seem to ask for any payment related argument but the order dto tracks it, so I'm wondering if that is missed off? It's also something I would expect to be done at the end unless you're perhaps allowing the customer to build multiple baskets gradually, and the orderid is generated at the start as a basket reference (in which case perhaps there is a separate process for adding payment info)

---

At the end of all this, you perhaps need to sit down and map out your workflows first and what data they will need and aim to strike a balance between reusing one mega dto that tracks everything vs having a dto for every case and ending up with 1000 DTOs. These are the two extremes and you will almost never go there. There is always some element of reuse that can and should be applied to limit the maintenance headache. Feel free to inherit classes if they have sensible common base elements, but I wouldn't recommend you have a base OrderDto with the order Id and then DTOs for createorder, updateorder, cancelorder, addordershippingaddress, changeordershippingaddress, changeorderbillingaddress, reportorderreceived, reportordernotreceived etc - most of those operations only need an order Id, maybe an address detail or order detail; you can have a couple of dto; the base order (for operations like cancel, report received etc) and the full one (with null billing address if you're changing the shipping address).

You can use the name of the method being called to know whether it's the billing or shipping you need to change, or the client can just send a pair of modified addresses (both addresses need updating), a modified and unmodified address (update one address but not the other), a null and nonnull address (remove one address but not the other) ... and the server can process them all in the same way: the new address pair is the truth; overwrite the old data with the new.

This has struck a balance between the dto extremes; if we happen upon a situation where neither dto applies, then we can consider making another if no existing one is ideal. We shouldn't use fields for things other than which they were intended (don't use the credit card number field to store the phone number if they person pays by bank transfer) even if it is "just that one time" - perhaps adding a phone number would be an opportunity to extend the Address dto and call it something different like ContactDetail

Answer (score 0):

At first you have to know your business logic and the required business entities. Without knowing any details about the application's business, the business logic can always be viewed as a black box, which requires input, processes this input and produces output i.e. a result (IPO model).

With the IPO model in mind, you can now design your business entities around the business logic. Identify the business process, derive the logic and design the required entities (their behavior or attributes and relationships). Start to design interfaces to describe those entities.

Note that it is not the goal to have a dedicated object for each method, so that each object only exposes the data the method needs. Although interface segregation is a good approach to achieve this, by encapsulating data contexts or responsibilities.

Since you have expressed your focused on naming conventions, also note that there is no value in adding a prefix or suffix to the type name that describes their physical (e.g. `bool`) or logical (e.g., DTO) data type. There is absolutely no value in this naming style. It only makes the names ugly and degrades readability. This is the main reason why e.g., Hungarian Notation is obsolete today.

### Example

I assume that your business logic's goal is to create an actual order based on the data input provided by a user. This example of course is based on a very simplified process.
You can always use interface segregation to encapsulate responsibilities. An object that implements fine grained interfaces, can be passed around by this interfaces, allowing fine grained context related exposition of attributes.

**Data input business entities**

```
interface IItem
{
  decimal Quantity { get; set; }
  int ProductID { get; set; }
}

// Describes data needed for shipping related to a customer
interface IShippingAddress
{
  string Address { get; set; }
  string Province { get; set; }
  string City { get; set; }
  string District { get; set; }
  string SubDistrict { get; set; }
  string ZipCode { get; set; }
}

// Consolidates data needed to create an order. 
// Provided by customer order process.
interface IPurchase
{
  int CustomerId { get; set; }
  IShippingAddress ShippingAddress { get; set; }
  IEnumerable<IItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**Data output business entities**

```
// Result entity that extends IITem to add internal details like price.
interface IOrderItem : IItem
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  decimal Price { get; set; }
}

// Encapsulates contact details
interface ICustomerContactInfo
{
  string Phone { get; set; }
  string EmailAddress { get; set; }
}

// Encapsulates customer details like IsVip, or contact info etc
interface ICustomerInfo : ICustomerContactInfo
{
  int CustomerId { get; set; }
  string Name { get; set; }
}

// Consolidates the data needed for the shipping process
interface IShippingInfo : ICustomerInfo, IShippingAddress
{
}    

// Consolidates and adds data needed for managing the order's delivery process
interface IDelivery : IShippingInfo 
{
  bool IsInDelivery { get; set; }
  DateTime PickupDate { get; set; }
  DateTime DueDate { get; set; }
}

// The result entity
interface IOrder
{
  int Id { get; set; }
  decimal PriceTotal { get; set; }
  string Status { get; set; }
  string PaymentMethod { get; set; }

  IDelivery DeliveryInfo { get; set; }
  ICollection<IOrderItem> Items { get; set; }
}
```

**Business logic**

```
public IOrder CreateOrder(IPurchase purchase)
{
  // Get the result item info that contains actual price etc
  ICollection<IOrderItem> orderItems = GetOrderItems(purchase.Items);

  ICustomerInfo customer = GetCustomer(purchase.CustomerId);

  IShippingInfo shippingInfo = CreateShippingInfo(purchase.ShippingAddress, customer);

  IOrder result = CreateOrderItem(orderItems, shippingInfo);
  return result;
}

public void SendConfimationMail(ICustomerContactInfo contactInfo)
{  
  SendMailTo(contactInfo.EmailAddress, message);
}

public void OrderDeliveryService(IShippingInfo shippingInfo)
{  
  SubmitDeliveryOrder(shippingInfo);
}
```

**Example**

```
public static Main()
{
  IPurchase purchase = CollectOrderDataFromUser();
  IOrder orderItem = CreateOrder(purchase);
 
  // Only pass the ICustomerContactInfo part of IDelivery as argument
  SendConfimationMail(orderItem.DeliveryInfo);

  // Only pass the IShippingInfo part of IDelivery as argument
  OrderDeliveryService(orderItem.DeliveryInfo);
}
```

The degree of segregation or the design of the interfaces may not make much sense for you. But the goal of this example is to provide a raw and basic example on how to design business entities, that reflect the business logic, which reflects the real life business process. It shows how interface segregation helps to pass around only a specific context (interface) of an object to enforce encapsulation or to limit greediness.